# taking strings from excel cells and entering them into a text box on a website

Tags: java, jexcelapi

Hi I'm trying to write a program in java, with the jexcel api that takes the text in every cell in the first column of an excel spreadsheet, and then entering it into a text box online (for example, google translate), and then automatically processing (or for this example's sake, translating) it, taking the result, and putting them into the corresponding cells

is this possible? and if so, how would one do this?

thanks.

Comment: Can you break your question into pieces, that is, can you isolate the portion of this that you have trouble with?

Comment: I'd mainly like to know the methods associated with handling the tasks  dealing with google translate (like how to automatically enter the text into the textfield, as well as clicking the 'translate' button)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to enter any text in any text field, because in the end, when you press the *Translate* button, you just send a GET request to Google Translate. Just send a GET HTTP request to the following URL, and you'll get the result:

```
http://translate.google.fr/#en|fr|hello%20world
```